# SSTA analysis using Cadence SoC Encounter

Tags: spice, cadence, timing-analysis

I would like to do SSTA analysis using Cadence SoC Encounter. This tool requires the SPICE netlist. Does the costumers have access to TSMC's or any other vendor's spice netlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will most likely not be able to access the latest spice netlist of any of the vendors unless you sign an NDA and/or pursue research in this area. You can create your own spice netlists for simple analysis.